# Find rows that have same value in one column and other values in another column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have a PostgreSQL database that stores users in a `users` table and conversations they take part in a `conversation` table. Since each user can take part in multiple conversations and each conversation can involve multiple users, I have a `conversation_user` linking table to track which users are participating in each conversation:

```
# conversation_user
id  |  conversation_id | user_id
----+------------------+--------
1   |                1 |      32
2   |                1 |       3
3   |                2 |      32
4   |                2 |       3
5   |                2 |       4
```

In the above table, user 32 is having one conversation with just user 3 and another with both 3 and user 4.  How would I write a query that would show that there is a conversation between just user 32 and user 3?

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT conversation_id AS cid,
       user_id
FROM conversation_user
GROUP BY cid HAVING count(*) = 2
AND (user_id = 32
     OR user_id = 3);

SELECT conversation_id AS cid,
   user_id
FROM conversation_user
GROUP BY (cid HAVING count(*) = 2
AND (user_id = 32
     OR user_id = 3));

SELECT conversation_id AS cid,
       user_id
FROM conversation_user
WHERE (user_id = 32)
  OR (user_id = 3)
GROUP BY cid HAVING count(*) = 2;
```

These queries throw an error that says that user_id must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause or be used in an aggregate function. Putting them in an aggregate function (e.g. `MIN` or `MAX`) doesn't sound appropriate. I thought that my first two attempts were putting them in the `GROUP BY` clause.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to find all 2-user conversations? Or just those for user 32?

Comment: Is your desired output just the conversation ID or also the participants?

Comment: It's always good form to include your version of Postgres and a table definition - which would show relevant constraints.

Comment: Good point Erwin.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a case of **relational division**. We have assembled an arsenal of techniques under this related question:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879)

The special difficulty is to exclude additional users. There are basically 4 techniques.

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

I suggest `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL`:

```
SELECT cu1.conversation_id
FROM        conversation_user cu1
JOIN        conversation_user cu2 USING (conversation_id)
LEFT   JOIN conversation_user cu3 ON cu3.conversation_id = cu1.conversation_id
                                 AND cu3.user_id NOT IN (3,32)
WHERE  cu1.user_id = 32
AND    cu2.user_id = 3
AND    cu3.conversation_id IS NULL;
```

Or `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT cu1.conversation_id
FROM   conversation_user cu1
JOIN   conversation_user cu2 USING (conversation_id)
WHERE  cu1.user_id = 32
AND    cu2.user_id = 3
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   conversation_user cu3
   WHERE  cu3.conversation_id = cu1.conversation_id
   AND    cu3.user_id NOT IN (3,32)
   );
```

Both queries do *not* depend on a `UNIQUE` constraint for `(conversation_id, user_id)`, which may or may not be in place. Meaning, the query even works if `user_id` 32 (or 3) is listed more than once for the same conversation. You *would* get duplicate rows in the result, though, and need to apply `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`.
The only condition is the one you formulated:

> ... a query that would show that there is a conversation between just user 32 and user 3?

#### Audited query

The [query you linked in the comment](http://pastebin.com/tNVifwmu) wouldn't work. You forgot to exclude other participants. Should be something like:

```
SELECT *  -- or whatever you want to return
FROM   conversation_user cu1
WHERE  cu1.user_id = 32
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   conversation_user cu2
   WHERE  cu2.conversation_id = cu1.conversation_id 
   AND    cu2.user_id = 3
   )
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   conversation_user cu3
   WHERE  cu3.conversation_id = cu1.conversation_id
   AND    cu3.user_id NOT IN (3,32)
   );
```

Which is similar to the other two queries, except that it will not return multiple rows if `user_id = 3` is linked multiple times.

Comment: Thanks Erwin! My understanding of relational theory is so weak that I didn't really understand either of your two solutions  though they both work. But I looked at your "filter SQL" [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879) and did understand "5) Erwin" and wrote this [query](http://pastebin.com/tNVifwmu)  based on it. It also seems to work. One problem is that it doesn't "scale". If I have to look for more users, I'll have to add more AND clauses programmatically.  This [article](http://bit.ly/1IdaWNY) also helped me.

Comment: @Robert: Your linked query is incomplete. I added an audited version above.

Comment: Your audited version works but I still think my query does too. Perhaps it appears wrong because I didn't provide my schemas? I've posted them [here](http://pastebin.com/WZn9vtKx).  I believe my query works because the "WHERE cu.conversation_id = 1" should eliminate other rows where user_id = 3.  I tested this by adding a third conversation with conversation_id = 3 that includes user3 and neither of our queries returns this third conversation.  In case I'm still wrong about my query and must use yours, I also show a modified version that I hope handles multiple users.

Comment: I meant to also say thanks again. I don't mean to belabor this question but it's a "mission-critical" query for a production app so I need to get it right.

Comment: UPDATE: @Erwin, In writing my actual code, I see why my solution is wrong and yours is right. I won't _know_ ahead of time what the conversation_id is! Your code doesn't depend on knowing it which is why your code is what I should use. Could you take a look at [this](http://pastebin.com/d8AZ3rqJ) and verify that I've correctly extended your query for three user IDs instead of two? Thank you very much for putting up with my ignorance.

Comment: @Robert: Looks right now for a conversation between users 32, 3, and 4 - *and no others*. Your index  `"conversation_user_conversation_id" btree (conversation_id)` is dead freight. Consider: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation to select all cids that only have 2 specific particpants

```
select cid from conversation_user
group by cid
having count(*) = 2
and count(case when user_id not in (32,3) then 1 end) = 0
```

If `(cid,user_id)` is not unique then replace `having count(*) = 2` with `having count(distinct user_id) = 2`

Answer (score 1):

if you just want confirmation.

```
 select conversation_id 
   from  conversation_users 
   group by conversation_id
   having bool_and ( user_id in (3,32))
      and count(*) = 2;
```

if you want full details,
you can use a window function and a CTE like this:

```
 with a as (
   select *
      ,not bool_and( user_id in (3,32) )
         over  ( partition by conversation_id) 
       and 2 = count(user_id)
         over  ( partition by conversation_id)
           as conv_candidates 
   from conversation_users 
   ) 
 select * from a where conv_candidates;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you want conversations with just 2 users, you can use a self outer join on other users and filter out hits:

To find all 2-user conversations and they're between:

```
SELECT
    a.conversation_id cid,
    a.user_id user_id_1,
    b.user_id user_id_2
FROM conversation_user a
JOIN conversation_user b ON b.cid = a.cid
  AND b.user_id > a.user_id
LEFT JOIN conversation_user c ON c.cid = a.cid
  AND c.user_id NOT IN (a.user_id, b.user_id)
WHERE c.cid IS NULL -- only return misses on join to others
```

To find all 2-user conversations for a particular user, just add:

```
AND a.user_id = 32
```